# Не устанавливается pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

Решил скачать сначала колораму, что мне удалось, но не дальше я попытался установить pyinstaller, чтобы скомпилировать свою простенькую программу (только начинаю изучать Python). Так вот, мне никак не удаётся установить pyinstaller, хотя с colorama-ой все прошло успешно. Вот что пишет в cmd:

D:\Python 3.8.0>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/c9/0b44b2ea87ba36395483a672fddd07e6a9cb2b8d3c4a28d7ae76c7e7e1e5/PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\python 3.8.0\python.exe' 'd:\python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\7060~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdd3cu43y'
         cwd: C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Здрасьте здрасьте\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n_0gvhgr\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\python 3.8.0\python.exe' 'd:\python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\7060~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdd3cu43y' Check the logs for full command output.

Помогите понять, что не так и как это исправить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Убирайте ошибки в аннотацию или код, чтобы они во весь экран не были. Вот возможное [решение](https://toster.ru/q/658299)

Comment: Возможно, проблема с именем компьютера и/или с кириллицей в пути

Comment: Мне помогла установка пакета `wheel`.